# What does "UserRequest" threadwaitstate mean?

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have a multithreading application. New threads are assigned to a threadpool and run.
I seem to have an issue where the number of threads is growing. It looks like some are getting stuck in a state "UserRequest".

My question is what does this state mean? Is it an interactive request? How did they get into this state and how do I get them out of it?

The MSDN article is less than helpful at explaining what these mean..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkhtkxxy(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: Additionally, using procexp many of the threads in this state have the following action on the stack:

ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x5a

Comment: Are you waiting somewhere in your code these "new threads"?

Comment: the thread uses locks when writing to a file. Im guessing the wait is in there, but Im not sure why this would happen

Comment: `UserRequest` is the natural wait state of a thread pool thread. The whole point of thread pool threads is to stand at the ready to perform work when someone calls `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` (or some variation thereof). So these "stuck" threads simply represent inactive thread pool threads. If you have a lot of them, it means you're pushing a lot of requests to the thread pool, and the runtime has decided to spin up new threads in response. This is only a problem if you can show that new threads are getting created despite the current number of them being sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. That's really helpful to know. The "issue" I'm seeing is that it sits happily around 20 -50 threads in that state and then rapidly increases to 500 - 700, but im not seeing an increase in the applications activity

Comment: for example, before lunch everything looked "normal" - now its increased to 835. Should it not spin down when no longer required?

Comment: The runtime isn't eager to decommission thread pool threads (I don't know the rules; they'll vary with version -- but it wouldn't surprise me if it *never* decommissions them, or only after an hour, or something like that). Creating threads is expensive; if the application needed 835 threads earlier, it'll probably need them again. That said, 835 threads is extreme. That shouldn't really be happening unless the application does something unusual, like calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` explicitly and/or quickly queuing up many long-lived actions on the thread pool.

Comment: In general, overuse of the thread pool is a sign that you may want to switch to something else, like the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl). Neither the thread pool nor tasks are a good match for parallelizing a large number of longer-lived requests.

Comment: It has now calmed down to a more reasonable 580. There's no explicit calls and tbh, they should be fairly short lived. Its good to know that "userRequest" is normal though. Perhaps I'll investigate TPL